# Mux switch: How to turn off the discrete GPU after switching on the Optimus from discrete GPU only, Lenovo Y540

Tags: nvidia-optimus

I have Lenovo Y540 which has an option to turn off intel gpu (Optimus) and 90% of the times I turn off Optimus and use the Nvidia GPU because of the performance difference but I switch on the Optimus when I need the battery life, so here's the catch:

when Optimus is switched on I get a black screen so I was trying to add a grub option to turn off or blacklist Nvidia GPU when Optimus is turned on but nothing works I still get a black screen, please help.
I don't want to use windows on battery!

tried:
nvidia.modeset=0
blacklist nvidia
module_blacklist=nvidia

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok so its fixed
In summary you need driver 460 or higher without anything like prime select.
Set the laptop on "Optimus on" then install nvidia driver without prime-select and in this scenario everything will be fine, you can easily switch them from bios.